# How can DOM manipulation like wrapping text in a paragraph element be achieved using only Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a Vue component which has a `contenteditable` `div` that lets users type in a message. When the user first attempts to create a message, I am using jQuery to wrap the text in a `<p>` tag. I cannot understand how this could be achieved using Vue.js alone...

***Vue.js component***

```
<template>
   <div id="Message" contenteditable="true" @focus="formatMessage" @keydown="formatMessage" @keyup="formatMessage" @keypress="formatMessage">

   </div>
</template>

<script>
  import $ from 'jquery'

  formatMessage: function(event) {
    if ($("#Message > p").length === 0) {            // if no <p> element when user interacts with div
      $("#Message").contents().eq(0).wrap("<p />");  // then wrap a <p> tag around the first child content
  }
```

}

Is it possible to do this using just Vue.js so I don't have to load the jQuery library for simple DOM manipulation (which may cause an issue with Vue's virtual DOM being out-of-sync with jQuery's changes)?

Before `formatMessage()`:

```
<div id="Message" contenteditable="true">
I started typing here  
</div>
```

After `formatMessage()`:

```
<div id="Message" contenteditable="true">
 <p>I started typing here</p>
</div>
```

Is it possible/better to try to do it using Vue's virtual DOM? Could I somehow use `createElement` to create a new `p` tag and then update its contents with what the user is typing? Maybe thats not the way the Virtual DOM works I'm not sure.

Comment: Post some same markups also like what HTML markup looks like before calling `formatMessage` and how it should look like afterwards? Also, is it going to wrap every text inside `#Message`?

Comment: @palaѕн I just added some before and after code. Does that help? It kind of happens instantly so as soon as you `keydown` the text is wrapped in a `<p>`

Comment: @palash It works perfectly with jQuery though. Once `<p>` is rendered after keydown, all characters are inputted into the `<p>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You can use `v-if` and duplicate the code a little if you want to achieve something similar

```
<template>
   <div v-if="shouldWrap === false" contenteditable="true" @focus="formatMessage" @keydown="formatMessage" @keyup="formatMessage" @keypress="formatMessage">

   </div>
   <p v-else>
      <div contenteditable="true" @focus="formatMessage" @keydown="formatMessage" @keyup="formatMessage" @keypress="formatMessage">
     </div>
   </p>
</template>
<script>
export default {
 data () {
   return {
    shouldWrap: false
   }
 },
 methods: {
   formatMessage() {
    this.shouldWrap = true
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

But probably trying to match the styling of a `p` should also work.

Comment: But you are wrapping the whole `<div>` in a `<p>` element. Its only the contents of the `<div>` that need to be wrapped in a `<p>`

Comment: Is it possible to do it using `createElement` method in Vue?

Comment: It should. All javascript related DOM methods are available in vue.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use JQuery-like DOM manipulation in VUE, *VUE is data driven framework*, you need to store some data in component to trigger layout, for example

```
<template>
   <div contenteditable="true" @focus="formatMessage" @keydown="formatMessage" @keyup="formatMessage" @keypress="formatMessage">
     <!-- wrap 'p' tag, if 'shouldWrap'-->
     <p v-if="shouldWrap">{{content}}</p>
     <!-- without wrap-->
     <template v-else>{{content}}</template>
   </div>

</template>
<script>
export default {
 data () {
   return {
    shouldWrap: false,
    content:'' // text, you want to display inside div
   }
 },
 methods: {
   formatMessage() {
    this.shouldWrap = true
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Nice example. But the `content:''` variable does not come from any data source. It is the text that the user is typing at that time. How would you bind what the user is typing to the `content` variable?

Comment: @volumeone I assumed, if *users type in a message* you need some argument to bind input

Comment: I have solved it using plain Javascript. It cannot be done with Vue.js because "When the DOM is modified outside of Vue's control (so to say), it cannot detect the changes and keep up with them. In other words: when using `contenteditable`, you shouldn't put Vue bindings inside, because you are allowing the user to modify the HTML outside of Vue context. It's worth noting that `contenteditable` is not handled by defaut by Vue because it's very complex"